# How to hook TYPO3 Form submit

Tags: typo3

I need to hook into a TYPO3 form submit event.  Do I need to write a TYPO3 Extension to achieve this?

I installed TYPO3 version 7.6.23.  During the install process I picked the default 'distribution' and I now have the "TYPO3 CMS bootstrap package".  When I go to the Installed Extensions screen I have the Form Extension installed (key=form).

I have a page with a form on it and I need to hook into that form submit event and do a HTTP POST to another site with some of the form data. Optionally I would like to prevent the form submit from happening, depending on the return value of my POST to the other site - so perhaps what I need in-fact is a 'before submit' event to hook.

Do I need to write an extension to achieve this?  If so how can I get started?  There are extension tutorials on [typo3.org](https://typo3.org/) but they imply I need to build a full blown MVC extension, which seems way over the top for my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of hooks in the 7.6 form extension you have two options:

1. Generate a JavaScript file which listens to the submit event, prevent it and run an AJAX call to submit the data to your external site. Depending on the response you can either do a manual submit or displaying an error message.
2. Upgrade to TYPO3 8LTS with the new form. There you have more possibilities to hook in and do your HTTP request.

Comment: I have been using this documentation https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/ApiReference/Index.html#aftersubmit Is this not for version 7.6?  If not, how can I find out which form extension hooks are available in version 7.6? In any case I really like your idea to use javascript. How can I add javascript to a page?

Comment: You can add JavaScript by e.g. `page.includeJS`, see: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejs-array

Comment: The documentation you linked is for the latest version of TYPO3. You can change the version in the lower left of the documentation page to your TYPO3 version.

Comment: Thank you, why didn't I see that! So I had been looking at the version 9 docs.  Switching to the 7.6 docs I can't see any api reference or hooks for the 7.6 form extension (as you originally said) so I guess I have no option but to use the javascript method?